# Simplify a formula with lots of IF/AND/OR statements possibly by detecting conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sap

I am trying to develop a formula that analyzes a specific material (corresponding to a `Part Number` value) that has multiple  values of `MS` tied to a hierarchy. This happens in many related ERP-using companies due to incorrect documentation and proper maintenance in the material master. The correct value can be determined solely from the corresponding `MRPcn` and `X-Plant` values, which are always consistent as they are based on the Client level within SAP.

[image: Spreadsheet screenshot #1]

I've conditionally formatted the `MRPcn` column so the values are categorized by color according to the legend. Conditional formatting was done because there are 500+ unique `MRPcn` values. This way, I could filter or write a formula using the colors if needed.

There are 20 unique `X-Plant` values. 7 of those are used for the `MS` values. These are `P2` (Production), `N2` (Engineering), `18`/`19`/`4`/`1` (Obsolete), and `15` (Global Ops/Service). These have also been conditionally formatted. Note that some of the `X-Plant` values don't fall under just these categories but these four are the most relevant and consistent across the dataset.

I have been trying to utilize `IF`/`AND`/`OR` statements and have previously done some advanced work with these, but the formula will end up large and unwieldy due to the large number of different unique values that need to be incorporated. Plus I'm also having trouble even creating a partial formula using just a small number of values.

Since the correct value of `MS` actually depends on the category of the `MRPcn` value and the category of the `X-Plant` value, I was hoping to somehow leverage the background color of the cells (which correspond to the category) to simplify the formula.

As an example, if the `MS` values of a part are `P2` and `N2`, and `MRPcn` = `C43` (Production Planning) and `X-Plant` = `P2`, we know the correct `MS` is `P2`. (The reason a material might have `MS` values of `P2` and `N2`, which are polar opposites, is because the part may have been initiated in SAP as an engineering planning part during NPI but then later down the road moved to production in a manufacturing plant and not maintained in the MM.)

Here is more sample data showing some corrections to `MS`:

[image: Spreadsheet screenshot #2]

Looking at rows `85:86`, part `1301386` has two different `MS` values of `18` and `P2` which denote Discontinued/Obsolete and Production, an `MRPcn` that is Engineering, and an `X-Plant` that is Discontinued, so it's likely that that part needs its `MS` to be `18` (Obsolete).

**Acronym definitions:**

- MM = Material Master
- MRPcn = Materials Resource Planning controller
- MS = Material Status
- NPI = New Product Introduction.
- X-Plant MS - Client level material status identifying a blockage or status of a material in regards to supply chain planning

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks for explaining your confusion. This issue with the blank rows being non-existent is that if there were, it would be ideal in order to separate different material. Since it isn't, when creating the formula and flash filling it would account for a different materials ms's and would therefore, output an incorrect code. I.e., if statements for Cell G2 and G3 analyze one material, then the output for G3, if false will refer to cell references in G4 (referencing a different material). This was happening in my iterations of the formula that I know are incorrect.

Comment: So you can see in the picture I've added, there are several different cases that can happen. In row 85-86, 1301386 has MS of 18/P2 which denote discontinued or obsolete and production, an MRPcn that is engineering, and an x-plant that is discontinued, so it's likely that that part needs to be marked as 18 or in other words obsolete. This formula worked to mitigate a lot of them, but for the most part when some material exhibited 3 or four different MS's, it would mess up the following material. Understand?

Comment: Correct, every part number needs to be referencing a single Material status rather than multiple. There are four different instances a parts Material status can be: E.g., P2 for production, N2 for engineering, 18/19/4/1 for obsolete, and 15 for global ops/service. Those can be depicted for a part based on logic for two different datapoints: MRPcn and X-Plant MS. @robinCTS

Comment: Correct, it can always be calculated based on the logic stated above. There will be a few instances where the correct formula will output the incorrect MS based on the referenced data. But those will be minor exceptions. There are over 500 MRPcn's and just 20 x-plant ms's, however all of those only fall into those four categories as mentioned above and is the purpose of why I have color coated them. So the question lies in if there is a way to put the material against the referenced colors. Because I know doing 500 different iterations of if statements is absurd lol @robinCTS.

Comment: @robinCTS I can run a Macros, but currently there are none recorded and this is an activity that only needs to be done once over a long period of say 5-10 years. I can install a UDF or whatever add-in that is needed, but fair warning, you are speaking out of my league now.

Comment: If I can autopopulate the entire list of MRPcn's and X-Plants and assign them a numeric value that sets different ranges corresponding to the four types of MS's do you think a CountIf or a different similar function may work for what I'm trying to do? @robinCTS Darn sorry I took so long!

Comment: @robinCTS correct, in the images it may not appear as if all X-plants scenarios are represented but of course being that there are 30k+ rows there are of course ones that are special and don’t reside in the typical four categories that I have classified above. Thus, in those scenarios, the answer then lies in the mrpcn. But if needed it doesn’t need to identify those, because if worse comes to worse,there are only a handful that I can do manually after filtering. Vlookups I understand better than any formula, how do you propose I build a nested statement that will output the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is already conditional formatting in place, I can think of at least three different ways to solve this problem:

1. Write a UDF to detect a cell's conditional format colour, and then craft a  formula with upwards of sixteen nested `IF(AND(),…)` statements or something equivalent.

   - This method doesn't have any real advantages
   - The cons are that using conditional formatting is slow, the UDF is not simple and requires re-evaluating the conditional formatting formulas manually, and that the required formula is long, with the "rules" embedded inside thus making them hard to see/modify
2. Craft nine (some very) long defined name strings and write a formula that only requires 4 nested `IF(…)`s

   - The advantage of this method is that neither conditional formatting nor any extra cells are required
   - The disadvantage is that the "rules" are hidden away in defined names and are very hard to understand/modify
3. Use three tables to define the mappings and use a formula that only requires three nested `VLOOKUP(…)` functions

   - The pros are that it does not require conditional formatting, and the rules are compact and very easy to see/modify
   - The only downside is that three tables are required

I will show how to implement the third method.

This is a test worksheet showing a sample of the data from the supplied screenshots, plus the three required tables with some of the data filled in (some of which is made up):

[image: Screenshot of test spreadsheet]

The first table contains a simple mapping from `MRPcn` values to the appropriate categories.

The second table contains the mappings from `X-Plant` values to their appropriate categories. If a value, such as one of the hypothetical `Z`s, doesn't belong in one of the four categories, the category value needs to be set to something unique. (I have used the `X-Plant` value itself.)

The third table maps the "cross-product" of the two categories in the previous two tables to the appropriate `MS` values. This is where the "rules" are defined. The cross-product is simply the concatenation of each of the unique values of the `Category` column of table 1 with each of the unique values of the `Category` column of table 1.

Note that the cross-products don't need to be in any particular order. Also note that for each uncategorisable entry in table 2, four entries need to be created in table 3.

Finally, as can be seen in the screenshot, place the following formula in `G2`:

```dart
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(D2,$I:$J,2,FALSE)&VLOOKUP(F2,$L:$M,2,FALSE),$O:$P,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Sorry was sleeping. Thanks for the thoughtful answer. Just to clarify, in the vlookup statement example, typically those can only reference the first row of the reference that is being looked up and doesn’t take into account the additional information about the part. But I think I’m gathering that, being that those two w(mrpcn and plant) will be consistent for both rows of data, it doesn’t matter. I like it.

Comment: @MicFitzgerald Exactly! I was wondering why you were talking about and attempting to reference the other `MS` values for the part. That's why I kept asking if the correct `MS` values only depend on the `MRPcn` and `X-Plant` values and not on the other `MS` values.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm below the reputation so I can't upvote it, but I did approve your edit, and have made just a few minor changes for future users! I'll be sure to delete unecessary comments

Comment: @MicFitzgerald Thanks for over-riding the rejected suggested edit. I wasn't sure if that was possible and couldn't be bothered searching Meta to find out. Once thing I did miss doing was adding the `worksheet-function` tag. If you could do that, it should make the question just that little bit better. I've cleaned up my comments. Now it's your turn ;-) ....This comment will self-destruct in an unspecified number of minutes . . . . . . . . . .

Comment: Lol I think I deleted everything that was unecessary or didn't aide the answer to the question. I won't forget! I'm currently working on implementing it on all hierarchies. It will take some time but not too much. I'll let you know if I run into any more issues.